# How To Get New URL on Tab Switch Google Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to get the current URL of the CURRENT tab in chrome. But this does not refresh when I change the tab.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = document.location;
});
```

Simple enough. It works well, but it shows the same location when I switch tabs. How do I overcome this?

Answer (score 3):

In your background page, you should add a listener to the `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` event, and inject the script inside the tab you want (for example a tab that has some URL matching a `RegExp` pattern) using the `chrome.tabs.executeScript()` method.

**NOTE**: since January 2021, use [Manifest V3](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/) with [`chrome.scripting.executeScript()`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/#method-executeScript) instead of `chrome.tabs.executeScript()`.

Fist of all, in your `manifest.json`, add the permission for the `tabs` API, and the `"background"` field, if you don't have it already:

```
...
"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "<all_urls>"
],

"background": { 
    "scripts": [
        "background.js"
    ]
},
...
```

Then, in your `background.js`, add the listener for `chrome.tabs.onUpdated`:

```
var myRegExp = /https?:\/\/stackoverflow\.com/;
// use a regexp to match the URLs you want
// for example, this will only match stackoverflow.com pages

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabID, info, tab) {
    if (myRegExp.test(tab.url)) { // if the url matches, inject your script
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabID, {file: "getCurrentURL.js", runAt: "document_end"});
    }
});
```

The above code will inject your `getCurrentURL.js` script, which contains the code you use to display the URL. Plus, you don't need to wait until `DOMContentLoaded`, because if you use `runAt: "document_end"`, Chrome will wait until the DOM loads before injecting it. So your `getCurrentURL.js` will look like this:

```
document.body.innerHTML = location.href;
// use location.href instead of document.location if you want the url
```

Comment: Hey, could we please chat? I've a couple of questions regarding chrome extension.

Comment: And one more question, what if I don't want this getCurrentURL.js script to be injected to every page? I've an array of hostnames of a URI which I want to inject this script. How do I perform the check in background and then throw control to the javascript injection?

Comment: @user2513722 we can chat, sure, but not right now because I'm not home. If you want, I'll add a comment to your post when I can.

Comment: @user2513722 if you don't want to inject on every tab, you can add a listener to the chrome.tabs.onUpdated event, and, when a tab gets updated, check if the URL matches your patterns, if so, inject your script. Here is [the documentation link](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated).

Comment: You can contact me on my email address: mehulmpt@gmail.com

Comment: It isn't working. I placed `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = 'Hello World';` Now it should replace every webpage I visit with Hello World text on load but nothing happens. No errors in console as well.

Comment: @user2513722 I edited my answer, see if it fits your needs. By the way you can send me a mail at marco@passivelove.tk

Comment: Looks like my `getCurrentURL.js` script is not inserted anywhere. I've set permissions in manifest as well, but it doesn't do anything, on any URL.

Comment: @user2513722 there were some little errors. I edited my question and also added a download link for a working example of the extension. [Download it](http://www.mediafire.com/download/lnte4jku1ly68um/extension-26384241.zip) and see.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63173/discussion-between-user2513722-and-marco-bonelli).

Comment: Please come in chat @Marco